# Why is my schema.prisma not automatically adding '@relation' when autosaving?

Tags: next.js, schema, prisma

I am building a NextJS app using the T3 stack. When I autosave my schema.prisma file it is not automatically adding the @relation tags, a friend is using the same stack and not having any issues.

[I have highlighted in pink the part I would expect to generate automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3qvn.png)

- I have tried to update prisma.
- I have the prisma extension installed.
- I have tried to google the issue but cant find people with a similar issue.

Comment: Are you using VS Code? And if yes, is the setting for formatOnSave enabled?

Comment: Yes I’m using VSCode and currently all other files format on save.

Answer (score 0):

Nurul pointed me in the right direction. I had to click ctrl, alt + shift to format the document, I then got a warning that Prettier could not format Prisma files, I was then prompted to select a formatted for Prisma files and I selected the prisma.prisma option in the dropdown.

Hope this helps someone.